# Postgres variables in select and error when using repeat

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following,

```
create table person (id serial primary key);
create table person_rating (
  id serial primary key,
  person_id bigint references person,
  rating smallint constraint rating_person_rating_check check (rating > 0 and rating <= 5)
);

insert into person values (1);
insert into person_rating values
  (1, 1, 5),
  (2, 1, 2),
  (3, 1, 5),
  (4, 1, 1);
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select
    round(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2), 2) as rating_averaged,
    ceil(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2)) as rating_rounded_up,
    concat(
      repeat('★', ceil(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2))),
      repeat('☆', 5 - ceil(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2)))
    ) as rating_as_stars
from person_rating;
```

I'm expecting the following result:

```
{
    "rating_averaged": 3.25,
    "rating_rounded_up": 4,
    "rating_as_stars": "★★★★☆"
}
```

I'm running into the following error:

```
Query Error: error: function repeat(unknown, numeric) does not exist
```

What's weird is that basic `repeat` selects work, such as:

```
select repeat('hello! ', 2);
```

I've also tried casting as `::text` or `::varchar`, but the error persists.

Another concern that I have is the repetition. For instance, in this case, the following sequence is repeated 4 times:

```
avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2)
```

How can I get around this?

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PoVMtiQM)

Comment: [`repeat` takes an `integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html), not a `numeric`, for the second argument. Cast that, not the first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [avg(any integer type)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) function always returns a numeric therefore the repetition of casting its results (`::numeric(10,2)`) is unnecessary. Also, as others have indicated the repeat() function requires the second parameter to be an integer, which will need a cast. Beyond that the manipulation of `rating` can be confined to a CTE, reducing the complexity/wordiness of the repeat() functions. Overall the query reduces to: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/W0AgDwOZ))

```
with ratings(rating_averaged, rating_rounded_up) as 
     ( select round(avg(rating), 2) 
            , ceil(round(avg(rating),2))::integer  
         from person_rating
     )  --select * from ratings;
select rating_averaged 
     , rating_rounded_up 
     , concat( repeat('★', rating_rounded_up )
             , repeat('☆', 5 - rating_rounded_up)
             ) as rating_as_stars 
from ratings;
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter must be integer:

```
select
    round(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2), 2) as rating_averaged,
    ceil(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2)) as rating_rounded_up,
    concat(
      repeat('★', ceil(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2))::integer),
      repeat('☆', 5 - ceil(avg(rating)::numeric(10, 2))::integer)
    ) as rating_as_stars
from person_rating;
```

Additionally, if you want to keep the code clean, I would suggest create a function that returns a rating based on a "rating" parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Also cast the second parameter of `repeat` to `integer`.

Comment: Can you please write this out as a full answer, completed with code